# How to make iCloud data sync user specific?

Tags: objective-c, synchronization, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

When I sync the user data (if the user request) to iCloud (using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`),
it syncs correctly. However, when I use 2 different devices, with 2 different apple IDs I see the SAME data on both and I'm still able to sync across them. So multiple users see each others data.

Is there any way to make the syncing user specific or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Some code that I use:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *icloudatas = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];

//save to iCloud
[icloudatas setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",
[defaults integerForKey:@"lvl"]] forKey:@"lvl"];


//load from iCloud
[defaults setInteger:[[icloudatas stringForKey:@"lvl"] integerValue] forKey:@"lvl"];

[defaults syncronise];
[icloudatas synchronize];
```

**Problem resolved:**

**I just changed my Apple ID int the App Store, I forgot to change in iCloud.
That resolved my problem, everything is working properly.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be copying the details into `NSUserDefaults` inside the app. This is how you are mixing up details from different users. Just use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` on its own.

Well, more realistically, you can copy data, but you shouldn't just always copy all data between both stores.

You should be observing `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` and `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification` and checking the reason for `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreAccountChange` (from `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangeReasonKey`). When you detect that the user account changed you need to 'reset' any local data either to default values or to cloud values (and prevent any update to cloud values before that happens).

Comment: I use it because i store the data in the device iCloud is just a choose able option. The user can save data and load data using a save and load button in the settings. There is a view where the user can see the data available in the cloud and in the local files. So the user can compare it. Here if I delete the app and i switch test user and reinstall it I see the same as i created with my other test account. Its all mixed.